# Google analytics is showing undefined symbols error while carthage build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics, carthage

I have a project with is using carthage for dependency manager. I have used Google Analytics Sdk in one of my framework , so when i run "carthage build --platform iOS" i am getting the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "<ClasName>.gaTrackers.setter : [__ObjC.GAITracker]", referenced from:
      type metadata for <FrameworkName>.<ClassName> in <ClassName>
  "<ClasName>.gaTrackers.materializeForSet : [__ObjC.GAITracker]", referenced from:
      type metadata for <FrameworkName>.<ClassName> in <ClassName>
  "<ClasName>.FSGALogLevel.getter : __C.GAILogLevel", referenced from:
      type metadata for <FrameworkName>.<ClassName> in <ClassName>
  "<ClasName>.setter : __C.GAILogLevel", referenced from:
      type metadata for <FrameworkName>.<ClassName> in <ClassName>
  "<ClasName>.gaTrackers.getter : [__ObjC.GAITracker]", referenced from:
      type metadata for <FrameworkName>.<ClassName> in <ClassName>
  "<ClasName>.FSGALogLevel.materializeForSet : __C.GAILogLevel", referenced from:
      type metadata for <FrameworkName>.<ClassName> in <ClassName>
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using xcode 8.2.1 and swift 3.0.2
Cartfile of **CustomAnalytics** framework where **google analytics** is intergrated

```
github "emaloney/CleanroomLogger" "3.1.0"
github "akashivskyy/GoogleAnalytics-Framework"
```

Cartfile of **CustomUIframework** where **CustomAnalytics** framework is integrated

```
github "sascha/DrawerController" "3.1.1"
github "emaloney/CleanroomLogger" "3.1.0"
github "MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell"
git "https://gitlab.com/Comp/iOSFramework-CustomAnalytics.git" "swift3.0.2"
```

So when the **CustomUIframework** is build using carthage i get the above mentioned error

Comment: might you post your Cartfile?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini i have posted cartfiles

Comment: Did you resolve your problem ?